# How is the Gibbs Free energy of Redox reaction during Electron transport of the Mitochondria utilized to pump protons across mitochondial membrane?

Tags: cellular-respiration, mitochondria, bioenergetics

I understand basics of the electron transport chain..that electrons "donated"  from NADH and FADH2 moves through redox centers within respiratory complexes I,  III, and IV (II is not involved in proton pumping)..Each step releases some energy..How is this energy harnessed by the respiratory complexes to pump protons across the mitochondrial membrane (against the gradient) to build up the Proton Motive force (which is ulitmately used by ATP synthaze nanomotor)?*.

Does  the Free energy  cause  conformational changes in the Respiratory protein complexes*, and the conformational changes ultimately pumps protons against the gradient? Does the details of  how the    Free energy is utilized depend on the Specific respiratory complex?
I am looking for a mechanistic explanation how the energy of redox reaction  is harnessed to pump protons against the gradients.

Comment: There are a number of questions in your post, which would require a fairly long answer. Please use the [edit] function to concentrate on the most important question, as the policy in SE is one question per question (more within reason if strongly related, some of which aren't in yours.) Thanks.

Comment: For the mechanistic part of your question, a good place to start might be Paul D. Boyers' Nobel lecture [Energy, Life, and ATP](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/chemistry/1997/boyer/lecture/)

Comment: I suggest you read a biochemistry text book. I would recommend Berg et al, and an old edition will suffice. You can pick up the 5e second-hand for about £5 on eBay (a search for Stryer Biochemistry gives more results).